# Significance of V < 50V for US certification purposes

Tags: certification

In the EU 2014/35/EU requires increased producer diligence and formalities when an electronic device used voltages greater the 50V ac either as input or as output.

Can somebody explain to me whether a similar rule exists with regard to putting a device on the US market? If so, does it make a real difference in practice? I.e. is the certification process significantly easier or cheaper? Or is product liability insurance significantly easier/cheaper to obtain?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely certain of this(I am not that familiar with US laws and regulations) 50V is considered "safe" under US standards, so if your device outputs a voltage below that it is a lot more lax regarding certifications and regulations it must follow.

So with an output under 50V it is not considered that much of a harmful device all in all.